# GET API code request failure

Tags: api, python-3.x, postman, import.io

I just started learning how to use API and I found some really usefull websites and apps like Postman and import.io yet I'm having problems finishing it without help.
I started my little project by getting a working api from import.io (It reads a website and can give you a working API that finds the info in the website)
My REST API looks like this:

https://extraction.import.io/query/runtime/7629f27e-ceee-4ce2-9a1c-cede623d2fc0?_apikey=[apiKey]&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimdb.com

To test and make sure it's working I used postman app and then found a neat feature - code generation.

The app generated this code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("extraction.import.io")

headers = {
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "2087cc79-77b5-0cb9-aa06-adc642978287"
}

conn.request("GET", "/query/runtime/1ac40e3e-f3eb-4290-88c0-e2651b8194a5?_apikey=[apiKey]&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.leagueofgraph.com", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

however the result is:

```
{
  "message" : "Your extraction request has failed.",
  "code" : 1003
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that has been generated has double escaped the "http://"

it should be `http%3A%2F%2F` not `http%253A%252F%252F`

Try this corrected code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("extraction.import.io")

headers = {
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "2087cc79-77b5-0cb9-aa06-adc642978287"
}

conn.request("GET", "/query/runtime/1ac40e3e-f3eb-4290-88c0-e2651b8194a5?_apikey=[apiKey]&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leagueofgraph.com", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```